# Exception while reading geodatabase file

Tags: android, gis, arcgis

i am trying to read geodatabase file (.gdb) and use it to get one of its GeodatabaseFeatureTables to load it to the map. However while creating its object, it's throwing "some kind of disk I/O error occurred " exception. I think this exception is related to SQLite error. Can anyone say why this exception is being thrown?

---

```
try {
     geodatabase = new Geodatabase(sdcardPath+gdbFilePath);
  }
  catch(Exception e){
       e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

---

Answer (score 0):

You say you're trying to load a .gdb *file*. I assume you mean a .gdb *directory*, which is a file geodatabase, right? Well, the Android [`Geodatabase`](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/api-reference/reference/com/esri/core/geodatabase/Geodatabase.html) class doesn't work with file geodatabases. Instead, it works with Runtime geodatabases, which are created with the [Create Runtime Content](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/create-runtime-content.htm) tool. A Runtime geodatabase is a SQLite file that typically has a filename extension of .geodatabase. At this time, ArcGIS Runtime for Android does not work with file geodatabases (i.e. .gdb directories).

Comment: Thanks. I figured that out and tried to create .geodatabase file from ArcGIS desktop. I loaded my basemap and a feature layer containing buildings and roads and went to File->Share As->Runtime content... and hit share. And ArcMap created .mxd file instead of .geodatabase file what I was expecting. FYI, "Enable ArcGIS Runtime Tools" is checked in ArcMap options. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: You're on the right track. You can use File > Share As > Runtime Content, or you can just run the Create Runtime Content geoprocessing tool. Either one of those can create a Runtime geodatabase for you. Neither one of those would create an .mxd; you got that when you saved your map document in ArcMap.

Comment: I am sure I did the same thing, but I will try it out again. Also, can you let me know, if we can edit such geodatabase in android? If not, can you let me know the procedure how to edit a local geodatabase file? My requirement is, I get the .shp/.gdb file. I need to load it into my android device and edit it in the device and save those edits back to the same file (everything offline). Later I need to sync those edits to the main file. I am going through the arcGIS docs but still not able to figure out the correct way to do it.